# How to extract words containing only letters from a text in python?

Tags: python

For example in the following text:

```
"We’d love t0 help 123you, but the real1ty is th@t n0t every question gets answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:"
```

How to easily extract words containing only letters:

```
love, help, but,... To,... tips
```

I tried

```
words = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z]+',str)
    for word in words:
print word
```

where `str` is the text. This does some work but I need to tweak it somehow.

Any ideas how to do it with regular expressions?

Comment: You probably need to read the rest of [ask].

Comment: I didn't saw any code here! did you have tried anything so far?

Comment: did you want `tips` to be returned?

Comment: @Kasramvd I edited the question

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks! Both solutions were fine, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @Misko don't waste our time posting questions showing no attempts/research.

Comment: @Misko: if you're going to ask questions here it's important to follow the rules.  Pointing out that you're not following them isn't "hating"; to use your phrasing, either abide by our customs or get off our site please.

Comment: @DSM As you can see I'm pretty new to Your :) site and I'm trying to post a good question, editing it again and again. If you can't give 10 min to newbies to post a good question and start bragging about it, get lost off Your :) site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use list comprehension.

```
s = "We’d love t0 help 123you, but the real1ty is th@t n0t every question gets answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:"
print [i for i in s.split() if i.isalpha()]
```

- `s.split()` will split the input according to the spaces.
- Just iterate over the returned items and consider the ones which exactly contain alphabets.

Comment: Not my downvote, but if you weren't in such a rush to be the first, you would have had time to try your code and see it doesn't give the OP's expected output.  So either the OP has made an error or you have.

Comment: the OP's desired output includes the word "tips".  Your output doesn't.  So perhaps the OP wants to exclude terminal punctuation -- or the OP made a mistake, and should be asked to clarify.

Comment: Nice solution, but how could we add the last word in a sentence? Ex. tips: -> tips? Could you do it with regular expressions?

Comment: Did you want `answered` to get returned? Then use regex `words = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b',s)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)', x)
re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]+\b', x)
```

Or with Unicode support:

```py
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[^\W\d_]+(?!\S)', x)
re.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', x)
```

See [**regex proof**](https://regex101.com/r/64uM09/1).

Use `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` to find words inside whitespace. Use `\b` if you need words between punctuation and whitespace.

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z]+                any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[^\W\d_]+                any character except: non-word characters
                           (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), digits (0-9),
                           '_' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```