# Extract words (letters only) and words containing numbers into separate dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract words which contain letter only into a new column, and any word which contains a number into a different column.

**Desired Output:**

```
              query    words_only contains_number
0   Nike Air Max 97  Nike Air Max              97
1     Adidas NMD-R1        Adidas          NMD-R1
2  Nike Air Max 270  Nike Air Max             270
```

**What I've Tried:**

I've seen the answer here which gets me some of the way there, but it's not exactly what I need.

[How to extract words containing only letters from a text in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552484/how-to-extract-words-containing-only-letters-from-a-text-in-python)

**Minimum Reproducible Example:**

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list elements
data = ["Nike Air Max 97", "Adidas NMD R1", "Nike Air Max 270"]

# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['query'])

# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to use this for? I often see such datasets with shoe-related data.

Comment: It's to pull out model numbers and brands to traffic shape an AdWords campaign. (Queries that contain brands and / or MPNs are more likely to result in a conversion and are cheaper to bid on etc. 

I'm just using Shoes to anonymise the dataset and keep it 'interesting'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract the words with and without digits separately, then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to join them separately:

```
df[['words_only', 'contains_number']] = (df['query']
 .str.extractall(r'(\S*\d\S*)|([^\s\d]+)') # order is important
 .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda s: ' '.join(s.dropna()))
 .loc[:, ::-1] # invert 2 columns
)
```

Output:

```
              query    words_only contains_number
0   Nike Air Max 97  Nike Air Max              97
1     Adidas NMD-R1        Adidas          NMD-R1
2  Nike Air Max 270  Nike Air Max             270
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zsEt2P/1)